# Phase Frequency Detector without dead zone

Tags: pll

How does the two inverter delay stage in Figure 6.14 on page 265 of [Design of CMOS RF Integrated Circuits and Systems](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/7260) helps to eliminate dead zone in Phase Frequency Detector ?

[image: PFD without deadzone]

How does the PFD deadzone-free circuit ensures that the SR latches will NEVER enter metastable state ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The delay does not eliminate the deadzone, and it does not eliminate metastability. However, it does make the circuit a lot less prone to their effects.

The problem comes about because the PFD is trying to align the logic edges, one from each channel. A logic gate will only have a constant propagation delay when it's starting from a settled state. As Div and Ref jitter with respect to each other, sometimes Div comes first, so the Ref signal propagates through a network that has already been disturbed by Div, sometimes Ref comes first, and Div has not yet disturbed the network, settled from the previous clock edge. This means that the propagation delay of each signal is data dependent, which introduces a lot of non-linearity in the transfer function of the PFD.

To add insult to injury, without the delay gates, as soon as the second edge comes along, a third signal is generated internally immediately to clear both latches.

The delay gates delay this third clear signal to let the latches settle somewhat before being cleared, which improves the non-linearity on the back edge of the pulses.

Unfortunately, this does nothing to fix the nonlinearity on the front edge, which means this type of PFD is not very good in most loops, and unusable in fractional N loops. However, it's simple, and integrates well with charge PLLs, so gets used a lot.

Comment: > The delay gates delay this third clear signal to let the latches settle somewhat before being cleared, which improves the non-linearity on the back edge of the pulses   <-- would you elaborate on what you meant by "third clear signal" ?

Comment: the signal coming out of the delay gates, sorry, it's called the Delay Stage on your schematic. There are three signals involved in the operation of this PFD. The first input edge to transition, the next input edge to transition, and the latch clear signal that's delayed by the Delay Stage, which I called the third signal.

Comment: Wait, it is a bit confusing on what you meant by "input edge to transition". Would you be able to label the corresponding signal naming on Figure 6.14 itself ?

Comment: In the quiescent state, both up* and down* are inactive, both SR latches driving them are 'unset'. The first of ref or div to make an active transition sets the corresponding latch, and the PFD produces an up or down level, this is what I refer to as input to transition. The second of ref or div sets its latch, and the PFD produces both up and down. At this point, both output latches being set eventually feeds back through the gates to the delay stage, which produces its clear level, which resets both output latches, I'm describing 'in lock' PD behavour, not 'out of lock' FD behaviour

Comment: I do not understand how the two SR latches in the middle region works. What are those two latches for ? Besides, what is the purpose of the 4-input NAND gate ?

Comment: The book version adapts the original version ([Cell-Based Fully Integrated CMOS  Frequency Synthesizers](http://sci-hub.tw/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/278348)) with slight modification.

Any idea why the book version does not require the [feedback signal of DOWN signal](https://i.imgur.com/XxdFRpV.png) ?

Comment: The stuff in the middle is for frequency detection, I can't be bother to trace out how those work, but race conditions and metastability aren't so important to the quality of the loop when it's off frequency. I prefer to use an N-state phase detector [like this](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4851784/no) for proper PLL work, it's much easier to understand, it works better in fracN systems, it's easier to build geographically distributed so minimising any crosstalk between ref and div inputs which can degrade the linearity.